# Suffix when copying TYPO3 content elements

Tags: typo3, backend

I'm new to TYPO3 and I often copy content elements in the TYPO3 backend module. All copies are suffixed. They are also disabled/hidden after copying.

Is it possible to remove the automatic suffix of a copied content element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can configure this** behaviour in TYPO3 **for each table with** Page-/User**TSConfig**:

```
TCEMAIN {
    table {
        tt_content {
            // remove suffix from copied record
            disablePrependAtCopy = 1
            // optionally you can set copied record visible with
            disableHideAtCopy = 1
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned already above, you can individually set this for each known and editable table within TYPO3.

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEmain/Index.html#disablehideatcopy